# Use async / await with fetch and foreach

Tags: javascript

This code should do the following:
Search all links on the current page and check for multiple errors.
The check should be before showing up the results on the page.
So I want to fill an array with errors and return it after all checks are finished.

```
interface LinkObject {
    element: HTMLAnchorElement;
    url: URL;
    checkTrigger?: HTMLButtonElement;
}

interface ErrorObject {
    element: HTMLElement;
    errors: string[];
    warnings: string[];
}


export default class LinkCheckTool {

    protected linksObjects: LinkObject[] = [];
    protected errors: ErrorObject[] = [];

    constructor() {

        document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach((linkElement) => {
            const button: HTMLButtonElement = document.createElement('button');
            button.classList.add('tb-o-linkobject__btn');
            const url: URL = new URL(linkElement.href);
            if (url) {
                linkElement.appendChild(button);
                this.linksObjects.push({
                    element: linkElement,
                    url: url,
                    checkTrigger: button
                })
            }
        })

        const errors = this.fetchErrors();
        console.log(errors); // results in an empty array, so need to use async / await here
    }

    protected fetchErrors() {
        const errors = [];
        this.linksObjects.forEach((linkObject) => {
            if (linkObject.url.protocol !== 'javascript:') {
                fetch(linkObject.url.href)
                  .then((response) => (response))
                  .then((response) => {
                      if (!response.ok) {
                          // push to errors here
                      }
                  })
                  .catch((error) => {
                      // push to errors here
                  })
            }
        })
    }
}
```

In this case, the console output of errors returns an empty array, of course. How can I use async / await and return a promise here?

Comment: Also after converting fetchErrors to be async, constructors cannot be async, so you would also need to do -> `this.fetchErrors().then(....`

Comment: @MrMythical  the map would work, but the `.forEach(async` will not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `fetchErrors` is not async here, because it does not return `Promise`. And since you try to call the function in the `constructor` `async/await` syntax won't really work in this context.

What you need to do instead is to use `Promise` callback here. You can apply the `Promise.allSettled` method. It will help you to wait until your requests will get resolved and then you can handle the responses one by one.

```
constructor() {
    // ...
    
    const errors = [];

    this.fetchErrors().then(results => {
        results.forEach(result => {
            if (result.status === "rejected") {
                errors.push(result.value)                
            }
        })

        console.log(errors); // will print you list of errors
    });
    
}

protected fetchErrors() {
    const requests = this.linksObjects
        .filter(linkObject => linkObject.url.protocol !== 'javascript:')
        .map((linkObject) => fetch(linkObject.url.href))

    return Promise.allSettled(requests);
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks. You made my day...